FastAPI in docker compose fails OPTIONS due to CORS for a React App on the same network
I am trying to make a "POST" request from a React frontend to a FastAPI app living in the same docker compose. Both containers are connected to the default compose network. The preflight OPTIONS request fails due to CORS.
I have a simple FastAPI app with a single POST route, "/calculate". I have a simple React frontend that makes a POST request to "/calculate".
I am trying to get both these services in docker compose. They are both connected to the default network. However, when making requests from the React app, the preflight OPTIONS request fails due to CORS. I have tried various CORS configs on the FastAPI app but none worked.
Moreover, making requests from my host via Postman to the FastAPI app works. Also, if I exec into the React container in compose and I make "curl -X OPTIONS ...", it also works.
I have hereby attached my code.
FastApi:
# Fast API setup
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.post("/calculate")
def read_root(calculation: PrimeCalculation):
    return {"Ok": "True"}

React:
    const response = await fetch(calculate_url + calculate_endpoint, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(request)
    });

I am very much stuck. I have tried so many CORS middleware configurations (setting origin to ["http://localhost:3000"] and so on, setting allow_credentials=False explicitly, setting expose_headers=["*"] and various other combinations of these).
I would be very grateful for anyone who has an idea why such a "simple" use-case is not working.

What is the URL you're loading your React app from? You'll need to explicitly add the base of that URL - with the correct host (so 127.0.0.1 will be different from localhost, http will be different from https, port 3000 will be different from port 80, etc. Being on the same network doesn't matter - your browser is the one making the request to the backend, not the React application.

I am loading my app from http://localhost:3000

@MatsLindh your comment helped me solved the problem. I have indeed forgotten that React is just a library and the browser is making the request to the backend
